# Create direct links to videos on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, download

How to create **non-expiring** direct links to video files on **Google Drive** that will download the file instead of opening them in the browse ?

Comment: Do shared links normally expire?

Comment: @w3d Sometimes my download manager ask for new URL to continue the dowlnload when I pause and resume downloads. However I need to create direct links to video files on Google Drive that will download the file instead of opening them in the browse.

Answer (score 3):

To do this you will have to change the URL you give to your users.

For example, the link Google gives you is something like:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=ABC123&authuser=0
```

You need to change the URL into the form:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ABC123&authuser=0&export=download
```

Basically what I did is:

1. Replaced `open` with `uc`.
2. Added at the end of the URL a `&` (Ampersand) and: `export=download`
3. I made sure the `id` part (in my example `ABC123` but in real life it will be something like `WFlEUEVTBRxVNGupYnRhVUk0B5UP`) stays the same!

Now when users click this link, the file will start to download. (You should encourage your users to use download managers, for speed.)